# mongodb query option

Tags: mongodb

If I have one field let say `extr_date` and I want to run a MAP-REDUCE where I want to use documents having `extr_date` greater than any specific date,

I have two options for that,

first I provide query field into result statement as given below

```
var res_acc = db.some_input_coll.mapReduce(map_func, red_func, {query : { extr_date : {$gte:any_given_date}},finalize : final, out :{ "merge" : "some_output_coll" }});
```

second I provide if condition into map function like given below,

```
var map_func = function(){
if(this.extr_date > given_date)
{
    emit({...} , {...})
}
```

...so which is recommended??

Is query with result statement reduces number of documents to be examined for map?

If yes, than how can I find that number of documents examined??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have an index on "extr_date", the first method will likely be faster since it will reduce the number of documents fed to map.

To figure out how many documents get filtered out you can try running the query separately with .explain().  Something like this:

```
db.some_input_coll.find({ extr_date : {$gte:any_given_date}}).explain()
```

Hope this helps.